# How do you open a file in the same directory as the class file Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

I have tried to open a file through command line but I keep getting file not found. The file is in the same directory as the class file.

```
 String filename = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" +args[0];
    System.out.println(filename);
      if (args[0].contains(".txt")){
        try {
          FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            t.add(line);
          }
          reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
```

Comment: Please add the output of your `System.out.println(filename);` to your question (via [Edit]). .

Comment: The location of the class file is completely irrelevant. A file path is resolved relative to the **current** directory, which is the directory from which you run the java command. Just like, when you open a terminal, and type `less foo.txt`, if shows the content of foo.txt in the current directory, not in the directory where the less program is.

Comment: the output of the `System.out.println(filename);` is C:\Users...\text.txt
It is where it is supposed to be

Comment: Solved. I had to alter the filename as the file was under a different directory